# Qual a vantagem de trabalhar com webSql?

Tags: javascript, websql

Estava lendo sobre webSql e me surgiu essa dúvida, qual a vantagem de trabalhar com webSql já que roda client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) é uma solução baseade em SQLite, que por se tratar de requisições sincronomas e ter restrições na implementação por trás da API foi abandonada pela W3C. Porém ainda está disponível em diversos browsers e é uma solução muito boa para armazenar dados no lado do cliente, para diminuir a necessidade de comunicação constante com servidor ou mesmo trabalhar com dados que só interessam ao usuário que está na página ou aplicativo web.

Para substituir o WebSQL a W3C tem como proposta o [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) que é uma solução um pouco diferente do usual SQL, porém assincronoma e permite que a engine que vai armazenar os dados pelo browser seja independente da API de acesso e escrita destes dados.

Por fim existem bibliotecas em JavaScript que permitem cross-compatibilidade entre browsers, usando a tecnologia disponível para armazenar os dados.

- [IndexedDB polyfill over WebSQL](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/)
- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/)

Answer (score 6):

Suspeito que a verdadeira pergunta seja: Qual é a vantagem em usar bases de dados do lado do cliente? (seja `webSql`, ou outra tecnologia qualquer)

BDs do lado do cliente (como o Webstorage referido pelo @utluiz) devem ser usados quando a informação é demasiado complexa para usar cookies, e quando a informação é transitoria/passageira/momentanea.

Nesses casos, ao usar a BD no browser do cliente, diminui a pressão no servidor. Em vez de se armazenar uma grande quantidade de dados no servidor, armazenam-se pequenas quantidades de dados em vários clientes.

Em Portugal temos uma expressão: "*distribuir o mal pelas aldeias*" ;)

Comment: Entendi, @dcastro mas no caso do websql é possível criar bases de dados e tabelas, fazer inserção e excluir dados com JavaScript, isso deixaria minha aplicação vulnerável, então não é muito vantajoso né?

Comment: Sim, e' possivel fazer essas operacoes, mas so' na BD do lado do cliente. Quando essa informacao entra no servidor, tem de ser validada - como qualquer outra informacao que entre no servidor. Cookies, forms, headers, etc - tudo pode ser manipulado do lado do cliente. Logo, tudo tem de ser validado.

Comment: ser vantajoso ou não só vai depender do tipo de aplicação. Nem toda aplicação web necessita de confiabilidade das informações contidas no banco.

Answer (score 3):

Posso estar enganado, mas hoje não parece ter vantagem nenhuma, já que o órgão que mantinha o padrão (W3C) abandonou o projeto por falta de variedade de implementações. Ao que parece, todos os navegadores usavam o SQLite.

A recomendação atual do W3C é usar [Webstorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

Fontes: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) e [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database)